# Data is not storing in the database in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-model, yii2-validation

I have two models in my project Employee visa model and visa track model.I want to store the primary key of employee visa table(ie.,employee_visa_id) in employee_visa_id field of the next table visa track.
The roles of visa track is:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['emp_id', 'employee_passport_id', 'country_id', 'visa_configuration_id',], 'required'],
        [['emp_id', 'employee_passport_id', 'country_id', 'visa_configuration_id','employee_visa_id'], 'integer'],
        [['validity'], 'safe'],
        [['remarks'], 'string'],
    ];
}
```

The roles of employee visa model is:

```
 public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['emp_id', 'employee_passport_id', 'country_id','visa_type', 'expiration_date'], 'required'],
        [['emp_id', 'employee_passport_id'], 'integer'],
        [['expiration_date'], 'safe'],
        [['remarks'], 'string'],
        [['visa_type'], 'string', 'max' => 300],
    ];
}
```

In the controller I try:

```
    foreach ($visas as $visa):


                $visa->expiration_date = date('Y-m-d',  strtotime($visa->expiration_date));
                $visa_track->emp_id = $visa->emp_id;
                $visa_track->employee_passport_id = $visa->employee_passport_id;
                $visa_track->country_id = $visa->country_id;
                $visa_track->visa_configuration_id = $visa->visa_type;
                $visa_track->validity = $visa->expiration_date;
                $emp_vid = $visa->employee_visa_id;
                $visa_track->employee_visa_id = $visa->employee_visa_id;

                //print_r($visa_track->employee_visa_id );die();

                if($visa_track->validate())
                {
                   // print_r($visa_track->employee_visa_id );die();
                    $visa_track->save();
                }
                else
                {
                    $errors = $visa_track->errors;
                    print_r($errors);die();
                }

                $visa->save(false);
                //$visa_track->save(false);

            endforeach;
```

**But the problem is employee_visa_id of employee visa is stored as Null value after saved in visa track**.How I solve this?

Comment: Check if $visa_track->save(); returns true. If it does not return true, you can investigate errors with <?php var_dump($visa_track->erorrs); ?>

Answer (score 0):

You are using a foreach  on $visas and then for you should use an equivalend  structure for visa_track  .. eg. adding a new object in each iteration
Otherwise you  $visa_track->save(); .. just update the same model each time

assuminng you visa_track model is name VisaTrack

```
foreach ($visas as $visa):

              $visa_track  = new VisaTrack();

              $visa->expiration_date = date('Y-m-d',  strtotime($visa->expiration_date));
              $visa_track->emp_id = $visa->emp_id;  
              $visa_track->employee_passport_id = $visa->employee_passport_id;
              $visa_track->country_id = $visa->country_id;
              $visa_track->visa_configuration_id = $visa->visa_type;
              $visa_track->validity = $visa->expiration_date;
              $emp_vid = $visa->employee_visa_id;
              $visa_track->employee_visa_id = $visa->employee_visa_id;

              //print_r($visa_track->employee_visa_id );die();

              if($visa_track->validate())
              {
                 // print_r($visa_track->employee_visa_id );die();
                  $visa_track->save();
              }
              else
              {
                  $errors = $visa_track->errors;
                  print_r($errors);die();
              }

              $visa->save(false);
              //$visa_track->save(false);

          endforeach;
```

Comment: But it prints the answer when I try print_r($visa_track->employee_visa_id );die(); and also other values(emp_id,country_id etc) are stored only the employee_visa_id is storing as Null.

Comment: print_r($visa_track->employee_visa_id );   print the actual value of the $visa_track model .. and the save update  this model .. if you don't create a new one  ..

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the built-in function [afterSave](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#afterSave()-detail) ? 
This gets fired every time after save/update

In your Employee VISA model do something like this :

```
public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes)
{
    $visa_track  = new VisaTrack();
    $visa_track->emp_id = $this->emp_id;  
    $visa_track->employee_passport_id = $this->employee_passport_id;
    $visa_track->country_id = $this->country_id;
    $visa_track->visa_configuration_id = $this->visa_type;
    $visa_track->validity = $this->expiration_date;
    $visa_track->employee_visa_id = $this->employee_visa_id;

    if($visa_track->validate()){
        $visa_track->save();
    }

    parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);
}
```

But even then you need to declare VisaTrack Object as [scaisEdge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3522312/scaisedge) already mentioned